# I added facebook like to my site and count increments, but it does not appear in activity feed

Tags: facebook-like

I added facebook like with iframe to my site and count increments, but it does not appear in activity feed. What could be causing this?

Comment: Is it supposed to appear in the activity feed?  Do you have any documentation on where Facebook says it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears in the activity feed only if the user publish it from the popup that appears right after clicking on the like button.

Comment: Can you explain more please? There is no popup when I press it unless I'm not logged in facebook, in which case popup asks me to login , but that's it.

Comment: when you go there : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and click on the like button you should see a post to facebook popup which appears beneath the like button.